# Segmentation Fault in Python multi-threaded Sqlite use!

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I'm developing a python code that uses Sqlite in a multi-threaded program. A remote host calls some xmlrpc functions and new threads are created. Each function which is running in a new thread, uses sqlite for either inserting data into or reading data from the database.

My problem is that when call the server more than 5 time at the same time, the server breaks with "segmentation fault". And the output doesn't provide any other information. Any idea what can cause the problem?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't open/close the connection each time a new thread is created. The connection is global and all threads use it. I am doing it this way for performance purposes. committing take so much time!

Comment: make a connection pool to use one connection per thread

Answer (score 2):

If you read the sqlite documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), you'll see that it says:

> SQLite support three different
>   threading modes:
>
> Single-thread. In this mode, all
>   mutexes are disabled and SQLite is
>   unsafe to use in more than a single
>   thread at once.
>
> Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can
>   be safely used by multiple threads
>   provided that no single database
>   connection is used simultaneously in
>   two or more threads.
>
> Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite
>   can be safely used by multiple threads
>   with no restriction.

So it would be that you're either in single-thread mode, or in multi-thread mode and reusing connections. Reusing the connection is only safe in sequential mode (which is slow)

Now, the Python documentation states that it should not allow you to share connections. Are you using the python-sqlite3 module, or are you natively interfacing with the database?

Answer (score 1):

My APSW module is threadsafe and you can use that.  The standard Python SQLite cannot be safely used concurrently across multiple threads.